# project-jdk-name not defined in IDEA-android-project

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

whenever I create a new android project in IDEA, I get an error

> Invalid configuration found. project-jdk-name is not defined.
> open-gradle-settings
> change-jdk-location

[image: project-jdk-name_not_defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXf2g.png)

then after

1. setting up sdk
2. selecting jdk (by clicking open-gradle-settings) [image: selecting openjdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsnoX.png)
3. when I reload gradle project
   I get another error :

   Module: ':app' platform 'android-32' not found. [image: platform-32-not-found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6a3N.png)

   but I already have android-api 33,32,31,27 installed [image: sdk-platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5LMh.png)
4. settings.gradle file

   pluginManagement {

   repositories {

   ```
      gradlePluginPortal()

      google()

      mavenCentral()
   ```

   }

}

dependencyResolutionManagement {

```
  repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)

  repositories {

      google()

      mavenCentral()

  }
```

}

rootProject.name = "Example"

include ':app'

6. build.gradle file:

   plugins {
   id 'com.android.application'
   }

   android {
   compileSdk 32

   ```
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.example"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
   ```

   }

   dependencies {

   ```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
   ```

   }

FYI:

```
1. I tried deleting .gradle/ and .idea/ and invalidated cache even this error
   still exists 

2. I tried changing api level to 27 (which I have), then executed clean, then after 
   clicking reload gradle project(by clicking reload icon at build console) 
   it shows same error with api 27  

3. Sometimes it shows a message like "sdk path not set 
   using /home/user/Android/Sdk/" with 

4. I noticed there are multiple platform-tools, emulator directories in Android/Sdk/
   They were automatically downloaded few times creating a new project
```

thanks and greetings

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use? If this is Android project, make sure the parent JDK is set for Android SDK: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-267233/Gradle-Idea-20211-always-reports-The-JDK-installation-is-invalid-on-Gradle-sync-Cannot-change-Android-JDK-location-Android#focus=Comments-27-4887905.0-0

Comment: IDEA version community 2022.2